# fetch email from id and send mail to that particular user in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

i have one view candidates form in my application ..in that i display all the candidates details and i display user_id also..i gave on button called send in the view page..

so what i am trying is when i click on the button i need to fetch the user email and send mail to that user..

view code:

```
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
```

```
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Vendor</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
               <th>Last Name</th> 
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Mobile Number</th>
              <th>experience</th>
              <th>CTC</th>
              <th>Expected Ctc</th>
              <th>role</th>
              <th>Current Location</th>
              <th>Desired Location</th>
              <th>Notice Period</th>
               <th>Resume</th>
              <th>Actions</th>


            </tr>
            </thead>

             <?php 

               foreach ($view_candidates as $idata) 
                {
                ?>


            <tbody>



               <tr id="domain<?php echo $idata->user_id;?>">
                   <td class="cell checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" />
                   </td>

                    <td><?php echo $idata->user_id;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->first_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->last_name;?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $idata->email;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->mobile_number;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->experience;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->ctc;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->expectedctc;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->role_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->current_location;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->desired_location;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->notice_period;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->resume;?></td>

                  <td><button id="<?php echo $idata->candidate_id; ?>" name="button" onClick="CallFunction(this.id)"  class="btn btn-info">send</button></td>
             </tr>

            <?php
          }
            ?>


            </tbody>
```

Controller:

```
public function change_status()
```

{

```
$candidate_id = $this->input->post('candidate_id');
$this->CandidateModel->update_status($candidate_id);
   $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'test3'
        );
           $this->load->library('email',$config);
           $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
           $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
           $this->email->to('someone@gmail.com'); 

          $this->email->subject('Request for contact info');
         $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin?requirement_id=29">Click Here</a>';
         $this->email->message($link);

           if($this->email->send())
           {
              echo "email send";
           }

         else
         {
          echo "failed";
         }
// echo true;
// exit;
```

}

Model:

```
function  update_status($candidate_id)
```

{

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('candidates_details');
 $status = $this->db->query("update candidates_details set status='1'  where candidate_id ='$candidate_id'");
$data=array('status'=>$status);
$this->db->where('candidate_id',$candidate_id);
//$this->db->update('candidates_details',$data);
//$query=$this->db->get();
echo $this->db->last_query();
//return $query->result();
```

}

Can anyone help me how to send mail to that user..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: ya..what happened is i already use ajax call..while click on button  without refresh anything..i update status in database value 0 to 1..

Comment: i have no idea on how to fetch that user email..please explain me..how to do that..

Comment: post your ajax code

Comment: <script>
function CallFunction(id){

  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/job_portal/index.php/Candidate/change_status/';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {candidate_id: id},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) 
        {    
            $('.button').text('FINISHED');

            
        }
      });
}

</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like below:

```
<script>
  function CallFunction(id){
    var url = '127.0.0.1/job_portal/index.php/Candidate/change_status/'‌​;;
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        candidate_id: id
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
        if(data == 1) {
          $('.button').text('FINISHED');
        } else {
          $('.button').text('TRY AGAIN!');
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

**Controller and Model:**

```
<?php
    // controller

function change_status()
{
  $data = $_POST;
  $d = $this->user_model->send_email($data['candidate_id']);
  echo json_encode($d);
}

    // model

function send_email($candidate_id)
{
  $q = $this->db->query("SELECT u.email_id as email_id FROM tbl_candidate as c, tbl_user as u WHERE c.candidate_id = $candidate_id AND c.user_id = u.user_id");
  if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    $d = $q->row_array();
    $to = $d['email_id'];
    $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
      'smtp_pass' => 'test3'
      );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
    $this->email->to($to);

    $this->email->subject('Request for contact info');
    $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin?requirement_id=29">Click Here</a>';
    $this->email->message($link);

    if($this->email->send())
    {
      return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      return 0;
    }
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136721/discussion-on-answer-by-pathik-vejani-fetch-email-from-id-and-send-mail-to-that).

Comment: @Pathik Vejani success function is not working in  ajax .. success: function(data) {
        if(data == 1) {
          $('.button').text('FINISHED');
        } else {
          $('.button').text('TRY AGAIN!');
        }

Comment: @Pathik Vejani..that ajax success function is not working ..so that's why yesterday i did that..so when i did that..this email is not working..

Comment: @user3663 there is no connection between ajax and email not working. must be some mistake from your side

Comment: yup..i did page refresh yesterday..so if page refresh is working,email is not working...and if page refresh  is not working..then email is working..why it happens..